# create multimap<string, vector<string> >

Tags: c++, string, multimap

I have been given a vector< vector > and I have to put them in

> `std::multimap< string, vector<string> > subsetsMap;`

with the first string of each tuple as key and the vector as value.
Here is my function:

```
void hashThem()
{
    int i,j;
    vector<string> temp;
     string first;
    for(i=0;i<subset_list.size();i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<subset_list[i].size();j++)
            temp.push_back(subset_list[i][j]);
        first = temp[0];
        subsetsMap.insert(pair<first,temp>);
        temp.clear();
    }
}
```

The subset_list and subsetsMap are declared globally. The declaration of subset_list is:

```
vector< vector<string> > subset_list;
```

which has data like: 

citrus fruit, margarine, 

coffee, tropical fruit, 

whole milk, tropical fruit, 

cream cheese , meat spreads, 

condensed milk, long life bakery product, 

abrasive cleaner, butter, etc 

But when compiling I am getting errors like:

> dm1.cpp: In function ‘void hashThem()’: dm1.cpp:124:26: error: the
>   value of ‘first’ is not usable in a constant expression
>   subsetsMap.insert(pair);
>                             ^ dm1.cpp:118:10: note: ‘first’ was not declared ‘constexpr’    string first;
>             ^ dm1.cpp:124:32: error: the value of ‘temp’ is not usable in a constant expression    subsetsMap.insert(pair);
>                                   ^ dm1.cpp:117:17: note: ‘temp’ was not declared ‘constexpr’   vector temp;
>                    ^ dm1.cpp:124:36: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template struct std::pair’    subsetsMap.insert(pair);
>                                       ^ dm1.cpp:124:36: error:   expected a type, got ‘first’ dm1.cpp:124:36: error: type/value
>   mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template struct std::pair’ dm1.cpp:124:36: error:   expected a type, got ‘temp’

There is something wrong I am doing, but since I don't know much c++, and could not find any relevant google result, any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subsetsMap.insert(pair<first,temp>);` is wrong.

It should be :

```
subsetsMap.insert(std::make_pair(first,temp));
```

Or:

```
subsetsMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::vector<std::string>>(first,temp));
```

Notice the `const` for the key.

---

Even better:

```
subsetsMap.emplace(first,temp); // Forwarding the arguments directly to the constructor
```

Comment: The 2nd one (the one with const worked). The other two (i.e. the make_pair and emplace one didnt work). Thanks..

Comment: @Shane I would love to see the day, when people stopped using such vague (you **cannot** get more vague) statements as _didn't work_..

Comment: @shane Welcome... what is your compiler?

Comment: @shane std::make_pair and std::multi_map::emplace are C++11 things. Does your compiler support C++11? It seems not. Since std::multi_map and std::pair wroks but both emplace and make pair not. It is not C++11 Compiler.. Consider moving to some compiler with at least C++11 or even C++14

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius :) I like them sometimes because they triggers my prediction system. However, I always make false predictions :D

Comment: @HumamHelfawi That does not make any sense, when talking in a context of describing problem to other people. We don't see what you see, unless you show it to us.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it was a joke ;)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Hello, My bad, I will be clear next time. I got many compilation error when I used make_pair and emplace. They are long and I dont exactly understand them. ( I am beginner at C++).

Comment: @HumamHelfawi the compiler is gcc 4.9.2. And yes you are correct, c++11 was not supported in my system.

Answer (score 1):

`subsetsMap.insert(pair<first,temp>);` should be:

```
subsetsMap.insert(make_pair(first,temp));
```

[std::make_pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) is used to make a `pair`.